# Best clustering technique for outlier detection?

Tags: clustering, outliers, k-means

I have around 15-20 points every second, and I would like to detect outliers based on

-their density along x-axis , that means if I am using k-mean clustering then I specify that in x-direction max of a variance is tolerated and in y max of b is tolerated. and a << b for this case.

Hence I get elliptical clusters.

Moreover, I think that clustering algorithms based on density clustering will suit my problem or if you recommend any other please suggest.

In the following figure, the most I am interested in the points which are near to -10 at x-axis and I would like to retain them rest the ones >-12. I want to discard them, but I would need a general clustering method to do it for all the data, as the point (-10) in this specific case, changes from season to season.

Thank you for your time, and please let me know if any further info is required or you have any tips . It would be most welcome

[image: Plot 2]
[image: Plot 1]

Comment: Why not use an outlier detection algorithm? Clustering is *not* a good tools to detect outliers unless you are willing to put very stringent models on what the outliers can look like

Comment: Indeeed thats a nice idea, I didnt thought about that, would you recommend any specific outlier detection algorithm?

Comment: Sure, as long as you have two variables (X,Y), I would have a look at the [OGK](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/robustbase/docs/covOGK). It's computationally very light and easy to grasp (the link points to an R implementation with references therein).

Comment: k-means doesn't use thresholds a,b - so you are talking about some other algorithm, but not k-means.

Comment: Yes, you are right! Because k means gives both x and y dimension the same weightage, In my case, I would like to give my x-axis more weightage and y axis come. I cannot completely ignore one axis and when I give both of the axis same weight, during the transition, when the data is not concentrated in either of them, it gives poor results.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you insist on using clustering?

To me it sounds as if simple k-nearest-neighbor distance (and in fact, nearest-neighbor distance) should just *work* for you. And that is a simple as it can get.

Note that it is trivial to add weights $\Omega=\{\omega_1,\ldots,\omega_d\}$ into Euclidean distance:

$$
\text{Euclidean}_\Omega(x,y) := \sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^{d} \omega_i(x_i-y_i)^2}
$$

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, the problem is when I apply KNN during the transition phase( i.e. when the concentration of data shifts from lets say in this case -10 to another number like -30, I would like to detect this rate of transition for which I need to give weightage to the x and y axis respectively. I am looking for something similar as you suggested but in which I am able to give the weightage to x and y axis for the decision.

Comment: You can use weightage for distance computations easily. Use weighted distance functions.